# Failing to download file from URL that returns redirect

Tags: java, download

I'm trying to download a set of files from a remote server, to local files.

This should be very simple, and i tried 2 different approaches, but each one has pros and cons.

**First approach - Apache HttpGet/CloseableHttpResponse**

```
CloseableHttpClient closeableHttpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();

URL encodeUrl = new URL(UriUtils.encodePath(documentUrl, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name()));

File file = new File(tmpdir + File.separator + FilenameUtils.getName(doc.getDocumentURL()));

HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(encodeUrl.toString());

HttpEntity entity = null;

try(CloseableHttpResponse response = closeableHttpClient.execute(httpget) {

    entity = response.getEntity();

    FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile(entity.getContent(), file);

} finally {
    EntityUtils.consumeQuietly(entity);
}
```

**Second Approach - FileUtils.copyURLToFile**

```
URL encodeUrl = new URL(UriUtils.encodePath(documentUrl, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name()));

String filename = FilenameUtils.getName(documentUrl);

File file = new File(tmpdir + File.separator + filename);

FileUtils.copyURLToFile(encodeUrl, file, 10000, 30000);
```

I'm having problems with both approaches.

**1. With Apache HttpGet/CloseableHttpResponse:**

Some URL's have spaces or even strange chars in the name, for example:

`http://download-service/Document Number 2015 .pdf`

All files with correct names are correctly downloaded, but the files with incorrect names are having this error:

```
org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException: null
        ...
Caused by: org.apache.http.ProtocolException: Invalid redirect URI: http://download-service/Document Number 2015 .pdf
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRedirectStrategy.createLocationURI(DefaultRedirectStrategy.java:200) ~[httpclient-4.5.5.jar:4.5.5]
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRedirectStrategy.getLocationURI(DefaultRedirectStrategy.java:148) ~[httpclient-4.5.5.jar:4.5.5]
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRedirectStrategy.getRedirect(DefaultRedirectStrategy.java:221) ~[httpclient-4.5.5.jar:4.5.5]
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:122) ~[httpclient-4.5.5.jar:4.5.5]
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185) ~[httpclient-4.5.5.jar:4.5.5]
        ... 108 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 48: http://download-service/Document Number 2015 .pdf
        at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(URI.java:2848) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
        at java.net.URI$Parser.checkChars(URI.java:3021) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
        at java.net.URI$Parser.parseHierarchical(URI.java:3105) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
        at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3053) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
        at java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:588) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRedirectStrategy.createLocationURI(DefaultRedirectStrategy.java:189) ~[httpclient-4.5.5.jar:4.5.5]
        ... 112 common frames omitted
```

**2. With FileUtils.copyURLToFile:**

In this case, the above error does not happen, all files seem to be properly downloaded, but all files are empty.

I've read the documentation on both methods, but i'm not being able to understand what is failing in both methods.

Answer (score 1):

I've researched on the following error, and started to suspect that the problem might be related to a redirect performed by the server:

```
Caused by: org.apache.http.ProtocolException: Invalid redirect URI:
```

As such, i created a CustomRedirectStrategy, that would perform the URI encoding on a redirect:

```
public class CustomRedirectStrategy extends DefaultRedirectStrategy {

    @Override
    public URI getLocationURI(HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response, HttpContext context) throws ProtocolException {
        try {
            String uri = response.getFirstHeader("location").getValue();
            URL url = new URL(uri);
            return new URI(url.getProtocol(), url.getUserInfo(), url.getHost(), url.getPort(), url.getPath(), url.getQuery(), url.getRef());
        } catch (Exception ex){
            throw new ProtocolException(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

This strategy was them applied to the CloseableHttpClient:

```
CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.custom().setRedirectStrategy(new CustomRedirectStrategy()).build();
```

With this change, all the files are now correctly downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try to encode your URL this way: [Encode URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10786042/java-url-encoding-of-query-string-parameters)

Seems, that in both cases you just have wrong URL.

Comment: I've tried one of the approaches described in that post, but i'm still having the same problems with the 2 approaches: 

URL url= new URL(urlStr);
URI uri = new URI(url.getProtocol(), url.getUserInfo(), url.getHost(), url.getPort(), url.getPath(), url.getQuery(), url.getRef());
String encodeUrl = uri.toASCIIString();